# Predicting after using normalization in training

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

After I've used any type of normalization in training, how would that effect my prediction in the future?

Let's say a close price of a certain stock was normalized between 0 and 1, and I trained the model accordingly, and I reached a satisfying accuracy. Now when I make a prediction using new data, do I need to normalize the new data also? If so, I fit it to what? Now I don't have a train or test dataset, the new data might be higher than the fitted data (which would make it above 1) or lower than the lowest data (which would make it below 0).

I know normalization helps a lot during training, but what about post training when I want to predict real data?

Comment: Please notice that SO is about *specific coding* questions. Non-coding questions about ML & data science methodology are off-topic here, and should be posted at [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead; see the intro and **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to rescaling the data. For this, you can add normalization layer to your model so it will automatically normalize input data so you don't need to do it as a separate step. For example, with TF you can do:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensofrlow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensofrlow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import Rescaling

my_shape = tuple()
my_data: np.ndarray = #some image array

def model(my_shape):
    input_data = Input(shape=my_shape)
    x = Rescaling(scale=1./255)(input_data)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation='softmax')(x)
    return Model(input_data, x)
```

Here we are doing with scale 1./255 for image data. Now, if you train this model (well, not this one, as it won't do much) and then want to predict for new images, you simply load image as array and model will take care of rescaling for you.

If you also want to normalize to have a specific mean and specific variance, you can add `Normalization` layer to preprocessing step.

Comment: "If you also want to normalize to have a specific mean and specific variance" the mean and variance of the new data is not the same of training/testing dataset how would that effect prediction?

Comment: Normalization is more important in cases where you have substantially different ranges of certain variables. Say, if variable a ranges from 10^6 - 10^8 and variable b is between 1 and 2 then any changes of weight affecting variable a would result in much larger change in the overall result. With long enough training a neural network will figure out that in order to predict better the weights affecting variable a should be significantly lower than b but it might take a long time. So in order to speed up you would want to Normalize your data. @KadiemAlqazzaz

Comment: My dear I don't think you are understanding me, let's say a closing price is 1200, according to train dataset mean and variance it was normalized to 0.6, but according to the new data mean and variance 1200 is now normalized to 0.8, wouldn't that effect prediction?

Comment: Well, I can't say for certain but it's easy to test by training a model with and without normalization. @KadiemAlqazzaz